# Jetpack splash screen Icon is not getting displayed when dark mode ON

Tags: android, kotlin, splash-screen, android-jetpack

I have created a launch screen using Jetpack splash screen API everything is working fine except the `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon` is not getting displayed when the dark mode is turned on.

Even though I'm using the material day light theme, forcefully opted light as default theme (`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)`)

I 'm aware of the considerations for the app icon detailed on the [google developer portal](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen),

```
<style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/splash_content</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">500</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.Main</item>
</style>
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: @Praveen yes, I have already tried the same but no luck

Comment: @Mable John I have the same problem, do you find the solution?

Comment: @Vahan No, still looking for a way to fix the problem

Comment: @MableJohn I think it is splash lib bug, it is still in alpha. Please write here if you find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

My icon was all black circle in dark mode but normal png in light mode. My solution was I updated my Splash API from androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-beta01 to implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.1.0-alpha02.